# Is there a pattern for bootstrap that turns a list-group into a table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a `list-group` that on extra small devices it displays a compact form while on larger displays it shows as a table. My problem is mainly with the table heading not looking that great.

Before I start going down the path of creating styles to style the heading, is there a pattern already out there to do this?

[Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I've done](https://jsfiddle.net/5g1d5jz1/). resize the window to see the responsive list become a table.

Example, note in the example that the table shows with headings misaligned to the cells beneath. This can be resolved by adding the class `list-group-item` to the row but it also styles it with the borders of the table rows.

[image: Image before style]

This can be resolved by adding `style="border:none;font-weight:bold;"` to the heading row.

[image: Image after style]

I understand my styles can be applied to perform this fix, however my original question was to see if bootstrap itself provides support to do this rather than my own custom styles. As my question states, "is there a pattern for bootstrap...".

Comment: Can you add a mock of what it looks like now, and what you want it to look like instead?

Comment: I could start mocking it up, but then I'd be developing the style while creating the mock :) The fiddle at the moment shows what it looks like at the moment, the main issue is the headings not being aligned with the rest of the table.

Comment: Well, yeah, you might accidentally solve your own problem? But what I meant was rough picture in MSPaint or something to give a visual indication of how it looks now, whats wrong with it and what you *want* it to look like. Your problem of the 'table heading not looking that great' is rather broad and subjective.

Comment: Added pictures, and a style fix, but I'm more asking for a solution that is already provided by bootstrap if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a naive approach to it, in smaller screen you will need to hide some columns. Did you find a better solution in the meanwhile?
https://jsfiddle.net/Kevin9696/2jxmyv9a/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header d-flex">
        <div class="col-3">Line Plan</div>
        <div class="col-4">Segment</div>
        <div class="col-2">SIB Date</div>
        <div class="col-2">Brand</div>
        <div class="col-1">Cabinet</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex">
            <div class="col-3">Animal Nation</div>
            <div class="col-4">Art/Photograpich/Blank</div>
            <div class="col-2">2021‑09‑06</div>
            <div class="col-2">John Sands</div>
            <div class="col-1">DK</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```